# php current_time() function returned wrong time

Tags: php, html, mysql

I  used `current_time()` function in php to return current time but it returns wrong time.

It is returning exact:`12 hours and 30 minute` before time to the actual current time even i changed `php.in`i file `date.timezone = "timezone"` , here i used timezone as `Asia/Calcutta`
and also used 
`date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');` function in php file.

And also tell me what in mountain standard time.

Comment: try using the date function
date('H:i:s')

Comment: Setting a timezone in PHP will do exactly nothing for MySQL.

Comment: `current_time()` is not php native function

Comment: then how to change timezone in mysql? @ deceze

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: i had tried it date('h:i:s') but it also returning same time @Soproni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To check the default timezone in php**

Create a new (blank) page with just this line of code. Place it in your server and open it in your browser.

```
<?php
echo date_default_timezone_get();
?>
```

**To print current date and time in php**

```
<?php
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Comment: it returns my defined timezone Asia/Colcata    you can check msbcon.com/employee/timezone.php

Comment: <?php
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s);
?>
it nothing returns :(

Comment: Great!! Mark it as the right answer. To rnevius... I tried to insert it as a comment but I didn't have enough points to do so

Comment: thank you,, but i am confused that why current_time() returning wrong time ?

Comment: I think that current_time() is not a native php function (as stated in one of the comments above). That is mysql language. But you are talking about php. And in php the corresponding function is date(). I will edit the answer properly now

Comment: yeah i was using this current_time() function in mysql query inside php,but i dont know that it will differ from date().

Comment: does it solves your problem now. or still getting the wrong result